# I am trying to Import a CSV file into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

> Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Solution" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
>
> Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "output column "Solution" (90)" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "output column "Solution" (90)" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
>
> Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "C:\Users\siddhary\Desktop\Created interactions1.csv" on data row 2.
>
> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - Created interactions1_csv" (1) returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

Please can any one help me....

The column called `solution` has data consisting of text & special characters, I have specified that column as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.....

Answer (score 0):

1st thing Id check is-  Open up your flat file connection manager, select the column that's being imported and see what the data type is set to -

[image]

Check the Output Column width and increase if its small